# Setting an attr_accessor instance variable in Ruby

Tags: ruby

```
mock_person = Object.new
mock_person.instance_variable_set(:@first_name, 'John')
mock_person.first_name # NoMethodError: Undefined method `first-name`


mock_person = Object.new
def mock_person.first_name()
    return 'John'
end
mock_person.first_name # This works
```

Is there a cleaner way to do this? Ideally when I use `instance_variable_set`, I want to specify that the variable should be `attr_accessor`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not entirely sure what you're trying to do but have a look at the [`Struct`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.3.1/Struct.html) class. For your example you may be looking for something like this:

```
Struct.new("Person", :first_name)
mock_person = Struct::Person.new('John')
mock_person.first_name #=> "John"
```

Comment: Trying to do mock testing without a mock library...long story :)

Answer (score 0):

You call `attr_accessor` on `mock_person`'s [singleton class](https://ruby-doc.org/core/Object.html#method-i-singleton_class) using [`class_eval`](https://ruby-doc.org/core/Module.html#method-i-class_eval):

```
mock_person = Object.new
mock_person.singleton_class.class_eval { attr_accessor :first_name }
mock_person.first_name = 'pancakes'
puts mock_person.first_name
# => pancakes
puts mock_person.instance_variable_get(:@first_name)
# => pancakes
```